# proof of identity theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let f and g be holmorphic on the area D, where there is a $z_o \in D$ in the area with $f^{(n)}(z_o)=g^{(n)}(z_o)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ greater than a certain $n_1\in \mathbb{N}$. I've got show the existence of a polynomial $p\in \mathbb{C}[z]$, so that $f(z)=g(z)+p(z)$ for $z\in D$. Unfortunately I've got no idea. I thought f and g have to be equal by the identity theorem, but obvously I'm false. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the identity theorem, $f^{(n_1)}=g^{(n_1)}$. Therefore, $(f-g)^{(n_1)}=0$ and so $f-g$ is a polynomial function.

Answer (score 1):

Since both are holomorphic both are equal to their Taylor series in a neighborhood around $z_0$, and by your assumption, these Taylor series are equivalent except for a finite number of terms, which gives you your polynomial $p(z)$. Since you then get $f(z)=g(z)+p(z)$ in some neighborhood, they much in fact be equal on $D$.